# Android studio build gives error in online mode

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I unchecked `Offline mode`. Now when I build the project,

**It gives this error:**

[image]

I am using *personal wifi*. So there is no `proxy`.

what should i do?

Comment: Are you using custom maven repo?

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti I am using maven repositories

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle files?

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}   @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.codetail.circualrevealsample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    lintOptions{
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':circualreveal')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
}  @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti here i am using maven deoendencies "classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3' "